# Remote Debug API entrypoint with Codeception on PhpStorm

Tags: docker-compose, phpstorm, xdebug, codeception

I'm trying to debug an application that is using docker [docker-compose], PhpStorm and Codeception. Xdebug's setup seems correct because if I add some breakpoint on the code then use the browser I'm able to stop on the breakpoint and debug the code with no issues. Also, Codeception setup seems correct because I'm able to debug the scenario placing some breakpoint in the ControllerCest file.

The issue here is when I'm trying to debug a breakpoint that is on the application controller from the Codeception ControllerCest file through `$I->sendGet(self::SERVICE_URL)`, it doesn't stop on the selected breakpoint.

This is my api.suite.yml

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - REST:
              url: 'http://app.local/api/v1/'
              depends: PhpBrowser
              part: Json
              timeout: 1000
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://app.local/api/v1/'
            headers:
              Accept: application/json
              Content-Type: application/json
              Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM
            curl:
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER: true
              CURLOPT_TIMEOUT: 10000
        - Symfony:
              app_path: 'src'
              environment: 'test'
        - Doctrine2:
              depends: Symfony
              cleanup: true
        - \App\Tests\Helper\Api
        - Asserts
```

Comment: 1) How your Xdebug is configured? Does it require "debug me" flag (cookie/parameter) or does it try to debug every single request automatically? If it does not do it automatically then you need to add such "debug me" flag to your request manually (as `$I->sendGet(self::SERVICE_URL)` line seems to do a separate request).

Comment: 2) If it's all configured correctly then please also check if PhpStorm is configured to work with more than 1 debug session at a time (may depend on what IDE version you use and when the project was created in PhpStorm as current IDE versions should already have value of more than 1 there).